# SQL Consecutive Date Cumulative Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, gaps-and-islands

I am doing some roster analysis and need to identify when an employee has worked for 5 or more consecutive days. In my table, I can extract data something like the below (note, there are lot more columns, this is just a cut down example):

| Emp | Start | First_Entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 23/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 24/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 24/06/2016 | 0 |
| 1234 | 25/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 26/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 27/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 28/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 29/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 29/06/2016 | 0 |
| 1234 | 30/06/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 3/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 3/07/2016 | 0 |
| 1234 | 4/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 4/07/2016 | 0 |
| 1234 | 5/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 6/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 9/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 10/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 11/07/2016 | 1 |
| 1234 | 12/07/2016 | 1 |

And what I am after is something like this:

| Emp | Start | First_Entry | Consecutive_Days | Over_5 | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 23/06/2016 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 24/06/2016 | 1 | 2 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 24/06/2016 | 0 | 2 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 25/06/2016 | 1 | 3 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 26/06/2016 | 1 | 4 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 27/06/2016 | 1 | 5 | 1 | Worked >= 5 |
| 1234 | 28/06/2016 | 1 | 6 | 1 | Worked >= 5 |
| 1234 | 29/06/2016 | 1 | 7 | 1 | Worked >= 5 |
| 1234 | 29/06/2016 | 0 | 7 | 1 | Worked >= 5 |
| 1234 | 30/06/2016 | 1 | 8 | 1 | Worked >= 5 |
| 1234 | 02/07/2016 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 03/07/2016 | 1 | 2 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 03/07/2016 | 0 | 2 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 04/07/2016 | 1 | 3 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 04/07/2016 | 0 | 3 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 05/07/2016 | 1 | 4 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 06/07/2016 | 1 | 5 | 1 | Worked >= 5 |
| 1234 | 09/07/2016 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 10/07/2016 | 1 | 2 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 11/07/2016 | 1 | 3 | 0 | Worked < 5 |
| 1234 | 12/07/2016 | 1 | 4 | 0 | Worked < 5 |

I'm really not sure how to go about getting the cumulative count for consecutive days, so any help you can give will be amazing

Comment: Please show us your attemp.

Comment: Hi Dale, this challenge completely stumped me but the answers (relating to "Gaps and Islands") pointed me to a great new understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a island and gap problem, You can try to use `LAG` window function to get the previous `startDate` row for each `Emp`, ten use `SUM` window function to calculate which days are continuous.

Finally, We can use `CASE WHEN` expression to judge whether the day is greater than 5.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  [Emp],
        [startDate],
        [First_Entry],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,f_Dt,startDate) <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Emp ORDER BY startDate) grp 
    FROM (
      SELECT *,
           LAG(startDate,1,startDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Emp ORDER BY startDate) f_Dt
      FROM T
    ) t1
)
SELECT  [Emp],
    [startDate],
    [First_Entry],
    SUM(CASE WHEN First_Entry = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Emp,grp ORDER BY startDate) Consecutive_Days,
    (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN First_Entry = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Emp,grp ORDER BY startDate) >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Over_5,
     (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN First_Entry = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Emp,grp ORDER BY startDate) >= 5 THEN 'Worked >= 5' ELSE 'Worked < 5' END) Status
FROM CTE
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b710d4c3b9a2abb4581fdae7c6b6e461)

Answer (score 2):

Probably someone would come up with a brilliant solution but this would do. Your problem looks like an "Gaps and Islands" problem. Finding islands of date ranges we can find out the rest easily. In the below SQL, @mindate is not a must, but makes it easier.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    [Emp] CHAR(4),
    [startDate] DATE,
    [First_Entry] BIT
);
INSERT INTO #temptable
(
    [Emp],
    [startDate],
    [First_Entry]
)
VALUES
('1234', N'2016-06-23', 1),
('1234', N'2016-06-24', 1),
('1234', N'2016-06-24', 0),
('1234', N'2016-06-25', 1),
('1234', N'2016-06-26', 1),
('1234', N'2016-06-27', 1),
('1234', N'2016-06-28', 1),
('1234', N'2016-06-29', 1),
('1234', N'2016-06-29', 0),
('1234', N'2016-06-30', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-02', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-03', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-03', 0),
('1234', N'2016-07-04', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-04', 0),
('1234', N'2016-07-05', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-06', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-09', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-10', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-11', 1),
('1234', N'2016-07-12', 1);


DECLARE @minDate DATE;
SELECT @minDate = DATEADD(d, -1, MIN(startDate))
FROM #temptable;

WITH firstOnly
AS (SELECT *
    FROM #temptable
    WHERE First_Entry = 1),
     grouper (emp, startDate, grp)
AS (SELECT Emp,
           startDate,
           DATEDIFF(d, @minDate, startDate) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp ORDER BY startDate)
    FROM firstOnly),
     islands (emp, START, [end])
AS (SELECT emp,
           MIN(startDate),
           MAX(startDate)
    FROM grouper
    GROUP BY emp,
             grp),
     consecutives (emp, startDate, consecutive_days)
AS (SELECT f.Emp,
           f.startDate,
           --       i.START,
           --       i.[end],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.Emp, i.START ORDER BY i.START)
    FROM firstOnly f
        INNER JOIN islands i
            ON f.startDate
               BETWEEN i.START AND i.[end])
SELECT t.Emp,
       t.startDate,
       t.First_Entry,
       c.consecutive_days,
       CAST(CASE
                WHEN c.consecutive_days < 5 THEN
                    0
                ELSE
                    1
            END AS BIT) Over_5,
       CASE
           WHEN c.consecutive_days < 5 THEN
               'Worked < 5'
           ELSE
               'Worked >= 5'
       END [Status]
FROM consecutives c
    INNER JOIN #temptable t
        ON t.Emp = c.emp
           AND t.startDate = c.startDate;

DROP TABLE #temptable;
```